# Accessing JavaScript's this from WebSharper

Tags: f#, websharper

I feel a bit dumbfounded at how I have yet to find how to access the JavaScripts `this` keyword from WebSharper client code.

I tried something like this:

```
[<Inline "$this">]
let this() = X<obj>
```

But this spits out `$this` in the generated js code which doesn't seem to refer to the correct scope object.

It feels that I shouldn't have to write any extra code though and that it should be part of the API.

Thanks

Comment: There's naturally more F# idiomatic ways of doing what we need and found how to do it. It would still be useful to know how to do this though.

Comment: Replied on FPish: http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/76515

Comment: Yes, I see how this is a non-nonsensical goal and replied on fpish.
Voted to close this question here.

Comment: Rather than close the question, it would be better to post an answer explaining why this isn't a good idea and what the idiomatic alternatives are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the general idea would be that when using WebSharper you will seldom need to navigate the DOM as you would with conventional site.

Having a wealth of combinators to create markup at the client side combined with the ease of RPC calls favors the pattern of creating all content on the client using javascript.

I.E. you tend to return data and in turn generate the markup interactively, only resorting to server-side markup as the need arise to create bookmark locations and useful links.

Therefore, you can generally keep reference to DOM elements when you create them simply by binding them to a variable for later use.

In my personal use-case, I wanted to access `this`, but later realized that `this` was a reference to the Kendo grid which I held a reference to when I created it. I therefore didn't need to use this.

Aside from that, there are the not-so obvious technical limitations imposed by an F#-to-javascript compiler of that nature. I feel uncomfortable detailing them here as I do not fully understand them, but feel free to see Anton's answer through the fpish.net link above.